# I2C Send Start Stop Commands using Python

Tags: python, rpi.gpio, i2c

I'm using a [PCA9585 board](https://www.controlanything.com/product/i2c_devices/PWM?sku=PCA9685_I2CPWM8W16OC) with an I2C interface to control LED lights.  I can control each LED separately or control them all at the same time. What I would like to accomplish is to program multiple specific channels starting with a **I2C start command** and then have the PCA9685 respond to the new programming when I send an **I2C stop command**.  Right now when I program each channel you can see each LED respond separately (like turning channels 3,5,7,9,12 off) with a short delay between each one.  That's not exactly what I want to accomplish.

I'm using python and the `smbus` library on a Raspberry Pi.  I have read the PCA9685 documentation, and there is a mode in which the system will respond to the new programming when an I2C stop command is issued on the I2C bus.

I just don't know how to issue the START and STOP commands.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the PIGPIO library,  it allows Bit Banging on  the I2C bus; it is also much better when interfaceing to the GPIO pins

Answer (score 0):

Each SMBus command starts with a start condition and ends with a stop condition.  There is no SMBus (or I2C) command which simply issues a start or stop condition.

You need to find an SMBus (or I2C) command which sends all the data you want to send or bit bang the protocol.

Comment: SMBus equivalent commands along with their low level transactions are specified here abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#i2c_open